# Possible error in String's split method

Tags: java, split

I have de next code:

```
String test = "A,B,,,,,";

String[] result = test.split(",");

for(String s : result){
    System.out.println("$"+s+"$");
}
```

The output is:

$A$
$B$

and y I expected:

$A$
$B$
$$
$$
$$
$$
$$

but, I modified the code as follows:

```
String test = "A,B,,,,,C";

String[] result = test.split(",");

for(String s : result){
    System.out.println("$"+s+"$");
}
```

and the result is:

$A$
$B$
$$
$$
$$
$$
$C$

other variation:

```
String test = "A,B,,,C,,";

String[] result = test.split(",");

for(String s : result){
    System.out.println("$"+s+"$");
}
```

the result:

$A$
$B$
$$
$$
$C$

any idea?

I need this for convert csv file to java objects, but when they don't send me the last column the code not work correctly

Comment: omg you found a wierd bug :S

Comment: You can try `String[] result = test.split(",",test.length());`, and you'll see that you get your expected results.

Comment: Yes!!!! you're absolutely right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution thanks to @ZouZou, is the next:

```
String test = "A,B,,,C,,";

String[] result = test.split(",",test.length()); // or the number of elements you expect in the result

for(String s : result){
    System.out.println("$"+s+"$");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

Comment: yes, but, if the empty string are not included, the result with the entry  String test = "A,B,,,C,,"; should be {A,B,C} ?

Comment: @victorpacheco3107 No. Read the docs more carefully, it says "**trailing** empty strings". Not "empty strings anywhere".

Answer (score 1):

i did this code right now, it worked fine for me, try this:

```
String test = "A,B,,,,,";
    int i;
    int countOfCommas = 0;
    int countOfLetters = 0;
    String[] testArray = test.split("");
    String[] result = test.split(",");

    for(i=0;i<=test.length();i++)
        if(testArray[i].equals(","))
            countOfCommas++;

    for(String s : result){
        System.out.println("$"+s+"$");
    }

    if(test.length() > result.length)
        countOfLetters = test.length()-countOfCommas;

    for(i=0;i<(test.length()-countOfLetters)-result.length;i++)
        System.out.println("$$");
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jeroen Vannevel stated this is documented behaviour of `String.split()`. If you need to kepp all empty Strings just use `test.split(",",-1)`